# connect points during multiple Matlab plot calls

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I would like to connect two or multiple data points during multiple Matlab plot calls. Below is some dummy code that shows what I am trying to accomplish,

```
function main()
close all

t = 0;

while t<10
    x = rand(1,1);
    y = rand(1,1);
    t = t+1;
    calculateErrorAndPlot(1,x,y,t)
end
return


function calculateErrorAndPlot(figureNumber,x,y,time)

    figure(figureNumber); 
    if ~ishold 
        hold on
    end

    error = x-y;
    plot(time,error,'.b');
return
```

Right now, I have to use '.b' to at least see the data points being plotted. Note that plot is being called with scalars.

Comment: Are you just trying to connect two points with a line? Is that your question?

Comment: Yes, but in the context of the question it is not simply connecting two points with a line.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is some code that works. However, I am open to suggestions or other code that may be simpler and/or faster :)

```
function calculateErrorAndPlot(figureNumber,x,y,time)

figure(figureNumber);
if ~ishold
    hold on
end

error = x-y;

h = findobj(figure(figureNumber),'Type','line');
if isempty(h)
    xx = time;
    yy = error;
else
    xx = [h(1).XData(end) time];
    yy = [h(1).YData(end) error];
end
plot(xx,yy,'.-black');
return
```

Answer (score 1):

You could update the [XData](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/chartline-properties.html#property_d0e542239) and [YData](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/chartline-properties.html#property_d0e542472) properties of a line already plotted to add a new point. For example:

```
function main
   fig = figure;
   ax = axes( 'Parent', fig );
   line = plot( NaN, NaN, 'Parent', ax );
   for t = 0:9
      x = rand( 1, 1 );
      y = rand( 1, 1 );
      calculateErrorAndPlot( line, x, y, t )
   end
end

function calculateErrorAndPlot( line, x, y, t )
   xData = get( line, 'XData' );
   yData = get( line, 'YData' );
   xData(end+1) = t;
   yData(end+1) = x - y;
   set( line, 'XData', xData, 'YData', yData );
end
```

Comment: @anr. I'm happy to help further but you'll need to explain what you tried and what didn't work.

Comment: @anr. My original answer was only supposed to point you in the right direction of using XData and YData. Not intended as a copy-and-paste solution. I edited it now to be more complete within the context of your main function. I suggest taking some time to learn and experiment with these line properties before using this solution.

Answer (score 0):

I would rewrite this, and remove the function:

```
time = [1:10];

for ii = 1:length(time)
    x = rand(1,1);
    y = rand(1,1);
    error(ii) = x-y;
 end
 plot(time,error,'.-b')
```

Comment: Instead of plotting scalars, it seems it would work better if you just created arrays. Obviously I don't know what your actual code looks like, but let me know if this is helpful.

Comment: yes.Thanks. The code above is a representative example of my code. There is no way I can now ahead of time x and y, so, they will be scalars. That is why I am using a random number generator. I imagine one option is to get all the x and y points on the plot and replot them as a line.

Comment: Well I'm not sure when you're getting more x and y values? But if say you're getting one set a day, you can just save the variables above to a mat file, and the add/concat the next set to the existing variables.
So if error was = [1 2 5 6], and you got another set of x,y. you could just load error and concat it, so error = [error, newerror]. And adjust your time accordingly.